# Refactoring quickly all the variables without UI

Tags: webstorm

In Sublime Text 3, I could press <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> twice while variable is highlighted and I could rename them on the fly while I see them changed as I type without opening any UI like <kbd>Shift + F6</kbd> does in WebStorm.

Is this possible in WebStorm I mean pressing a shortcut twice and renaming all occurrences quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>`Shift`</kbd><kbd>`F6`</kbd> will rename all possible occurrences in your proj.

<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd><kbd>`ALT`</kbd><kbd>`J`</kbd> will select all the  occurrence of the word you selected without UI.

<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd><kbd>`R`</kbd> will do a search and replace in the current active editor.

Please refer to the official docs of Jetbrains Webstorm for more info: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/documentation/

Comment: I know I can do these but I asked if I could do without UI. When I press Ctrl + R, a search box appears. Also Ctrl+D duplicates the string I selected. I have no idea how this is related to refactoring. Shitf + F6 brings UI too. I asked if I could do these without UI. Something like Ctrl + R Ctrl+R and editing the all possible occurrences at the same time in Visual Studio on the fly.

Comment: I edited my answer, see if `ctrl shift alt j` will do what you want.